# Maven unable to locate persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, persistence.xml

I copied the persistence.xml in every folder, but still maven showing unable to locate the file persistence.xml. Please help.

Error:

```
         [INFO] using jpaconfiguration task.
    19:19:52,652  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
    19:19:52,657  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
    19:19:52,659  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
    19:19:52,661  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
    19:19:52,663  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
    19:19:52,691  INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
    19:19:52,693  INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
    19:19:52,702  INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
    [ERROR] Persistence unit not found: 'myapp'.
```

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.myhadoop.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app-hadoop</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>my-app-hadoop</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate </groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1.GA </version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
                <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
                <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>maven2</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>jBoss-Repository</id>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>mirrors.ibiblio</id>
                <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-xml-files</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>hbm2hbmxml</goal>
                                <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-entities</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2hbmxml</name>
                                <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                                <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                            </component>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2cfgxml</name>
                                <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                                <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                            </component>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2java</name>
                                <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>

                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                            <persistenceunit>myapp</persistenceunit>
                            <propertyfile>src/main/resources/database.properties</propertyfile>
                            <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                            <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                            <packagename>com.adept.reverse</packagename>
                            <format>true</format>
                            <haltonerror>true</haltonerror>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <version>5.1.23</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>


            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Why are you defining a plugin as a dependency? (maven-resources-plugin?). Why are you [defining repositories in you pom](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/)? Aren't you are using a [repository Manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)? Why not using a more up-to-date version of the [hibernate3-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate3-maven-plugin%22) ?

Comment: Ah ...I have my doubts that you configuration for the hibernate3-maven-plugin (outputDirectory) is correct cause generated code should be put into *target/...* folder and **never** into **src** location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`